# How can we keep an java application running forever

Tags: java, web-services, microservices

I want to write an java application, which should be running forever. 
Webservice is a way to do so, but i don't want to run it as webservice. 
I just want to run some threads inside application running forever, I don't want to process any webRequest as such.

Can you please tell what are other ways to do so ?

Comment: Run it, don't stop it.  Why wouldn't a Java application run for ever?

Comment: `while (true) {}` - not what you want I guess

Comment: or if you prefer for loops over while loops `for( ; ; ) { }`

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve, but maybe it helps: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html

Answer (score 3):

Have one class with a main method that looks like the following:

```
final class Forever
{
    private Forever ()
    {}

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
           try
           {
               // don't do anything here
               // especially do NOT connect to any databases
           }
           catch (Throwable t)
           {

           }    
        }
    }
}
```

Put this java code on a space probe, running Linux, with an infinite energy source. Make sure it stays clear of planets, exploding stars, black holes, etc.

**Note**: Don't allow humans to connect to the probe.

This may not get the forever you desire; however, it may make it up until the end of the universe.

**Update**:
So far, I've been running this for about <strike>5</strike> 10 minutes on my development environment and it is still running! I may push this to QA soon.

Comment: Basically i want to run few queue listeners on a persistent queue and those should be running forever. But seeing GC and other problems, the above solution doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: You're incorrect. Unfortunately, given a sufficient amount of time, but still way before the end of the universe, the probe would eventually decay via quantum tunnelling and the emission of gravitons into iron-56 nuclei as per this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe#Matter_decays_into_iron. Please get your facts straight before posting them on the public interweb.

Answer (score 0):

You can have any application run forever using the threads (preferably over thread pool), but you should take utmost care about the GC. So you may have to keep a close eye on the instance management, Heap dumps periodically and fine tune the application. Hope this would help you!